# Upload large video file in chunk using Laravel and VueJS

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have a Laravel project for API and a VueJS project for the front end. I need to upload large video files to the server. My first question is, what is the best way to upload large files to the server with minimum failure?

I have decided to upload the file in chunks and for this purpose, I have tried two different ways.

**Using resumablejs:**

```
this.r = new Resumable({
  target:process.env.API_URL+'upload',
  query:{upload_token:'my_token'},
  headers:{
    Authorization: 'Bearer '
  },
  maxChunkRetries: 1,
  simultaneousUploads: 1,
  testChunks: false,
});
// Resumable.js isn't supported, fall back on a different method
if(!this.r.support) return alert('Your browser doesn\'t support chunked uploads. Get a better browser.');
this.r.assignBrowse(this.$refs.videodropzone);
this.r.assignDrop(this.$refs.videodropzone);
// set up event listeners to feed into vues reactivity
this.r.on('fileAdded', (file, event) => {
  file.hasUploaded = false
  console.log('this.files', this.files)
  // keep a list of files with some extra data that we can use as props
  this.files.push({
    file,
    status: 'uploading',
    progress: 0
  })
  this.r.upload()
})
this.r.on('fileSuccess', (file, event) => {
  this.findFile(file).status = 'success'
})
this.r.on('fileError', (file, event) => {
  this.findFile(file).status = 'error'
})
this.r.on('fileRetry', (file, event) => {
  this.findFile(file).status = 'retrying'
})
this.r.on('fileProgress', (file) => {
  // console.log('fileProgress', progress)
  const localFile = this.findFile(file)
  // if we are doing multiple chunks we may get a lower progress number if one chunk response comes back early
  const progress = file.progress()
  if( progress > localFile.progress)
    localFile.progress = progress
})
```

**Creating manual chunk:**

```
upload() {
  const url = 'upload'
  this.$axios.post(url, this.formData).then(() => {
    this.chunks.shift()
  }).catch((error) => {
  })
},
createChunks() {
  let size = 1024 * 1000, chunks = Math.ceil(this.file.size / size)

  for (let i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
    this.chunks.push(this.file.slice(
      i * size, Math.min(i * size + size, this.file.size), this.file.type
    ))
  }
}
```

Both codes give me the same output in the backend. The next part is to append the chunk files into one final file. For this, I have written the following code in Laravel-

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('file');
    Storage::disk('local')->append('output/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->get());
}
```

Now, here is my problem. I can upload large files using the code above. But the output is not right I think although the output and input file size is the same. The output video file is not playable. It plays first few seconds then it stops. I think only the first chunk is playable. I have tested with a 10MB video file.
Then I have tested with a 10MB pdf file, after uploading the pdf file, I can open the output file and the output is ok. But for the video file, I cannot play the whole video. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the PHP part, I was getting an extra line break for appended chunk part, so I had to change the part from `Storage::disk('local')->append('output/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->get());`
to `Storage::disk('local')->append('output/' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), $file->get(),null);`